# Should I remove old python installation when I recompile it from sources

Tags: python

Once I has installed python 3.7.1 from the sources. I need update a version of it between 3.7.1 and 3.7.5. And backwards.

I do not need both at the same time. I want to use the same directory for installed python. Should I remove the content from the folder I had before specified as ./configure --prefix=... when compiling past time?

Question is both for upgrading and downgrading cases, the only idea that major version (3.7 here) remains the same, if this even matters.

Comment: maybe dont change the system default and make own folder where specified the packages, and have a mechnisam when if compiling fail then you can revert back

Comment: This really boils down to whether or not you need both microversions in the future or not. If you do, don't constantly up/downgrade from one version to the other. Install both in separate prefixes, and use virtual environments to select the one you need at the moment.

Comment: @chepner do not need both at the same time. Will add in the question.

Comment: You could remove the old version before installing the new version, but for safety, I would do this atomically: install the new version in a separate (temporary) location, and once you've confirmed it works, *then* remove the old version and move the new version into its place.

Comment: *Don't* simply try to install the new version *on top* of the old version. In general, you never know what cruft might get left behind because it wasn't overwritten.

Comment: I did actually this today, reinstalled on the top of existing installation. It works still, though, but I'm looking forward for ideas around.